# Проблемы с Sympy при решении уравнения

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

я пытаюсь решить уравнение с помощью sympy,  но мне выводит корни не совсем в нормальном виде, как это можно поправить?
Вот код программы, язык программирования Python 3.7

```
import sympy as sp

def f(x):
   return 2*x**4-3*x**2+75*x-10000

def reshenie():
     x = sp.Symbol('x')
     a = sp.solve(f(x),x)
     print(a)

reshenie()
```

Файл с выводом консоли:
[image: Файл с выводом консоли]

Корни которые должны получится при решении данного уравнения:
[image: Корни которые должны получится при решении данного уравнения]

Comment: Если подставить -8.585 или 8.32 в уравнение, то 0 не получится.

Comment: это mathcad посчитал

Comment: Ну значит он округляет я попробовал z3 солвером 8.3200401239 и -8.5851916178, но это тоже округленные корни. Может поэтому симпай такие корни странные и выдает?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить численные (приближенные) решения вместо аналитических (точных) просто примените метод [`.evalf()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.evalf) к каждому из полученных решений:

```
import sympy as sp

def f(x):
   return 2*x**4-3*x**2+75*x-10000

x = sp.Symbol('x')
a = sp.solve(f(x), x)

for result in a:
    print(result.evalf())
```

Вывод:

```
8.32004012395616
0.132575746935762 - 8.36551658406133*I
0.132575746935762 + 8.36551658406133*I
-8.58519161782768
```